# Is Colin Moshmans Book Still A Relevant Micro SNG Reference

Tags: books, sit-and-go

I am looking for a book specifically about micro SnG games.

Everywhere I look people are saying that I must get Colin Moshmans book SnG strategy but this book was written in 2008. Given that poker is changing at such a fast pace at the moment is this book still relevant? Is there a better book out there?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When it comes to micro stakes the think you say about "poker is changing at fast pace" Doesn't really apply to micro stakes. It does apply to mid stakes and above. But that's just because those players try to BEAT the game. While most micro stakes players try to PLAY the game. Of course over the years some micro stakes players got better and some of them even know now what VP/IP and other stats are, but they don't know what to do with it most of the time and make a lot of mistakes. Most books you will read about beating SNG will focus on those mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Although poker is changing all the time fundamentally the game is still the same. Its only really peoples strategies that change.

If this book has been recommended in several places then its obviously a good book even if it is 5 years old. So you should probably take a look at it, if you get the opportunity.

In my opinon the best way to continue to learn is to read about poker on the internet and by being on sites like this. That way you tend to keep up with the latest trends etc.

Comment: Thanks. Although it is the same game you are playing against other people and their strategies so when they change you need to change. For example if you picked up supersytem and played online in micro sng and even at higher stakes you will get crushed (or at least not doe that well)

Comment: @hmmmm I think that, when it comes to micro-stakes, the fact that the game changes is insignificant. People playing at that level will not take advantage of new strategies anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Even in 2015, The moshman's book is considered the top-book for `SNGs`.
Before this book came out, the best one for SNGs was `Earn $30,000 Per Month Playing Online Poker` by Ryan Wiseman.

Having read both of them, i say that `Sit 'n Go Strategy: Expert advice for beating one table poker tournaments` is way better than `$30,000...` book. It gives many, many examples on many concepts.

Other players also recommend `Secrets of Sit'n'gos` by Phil Shaw, but this also came on 2008, and personally i found it a bit difficult book and in no way as *easy* as the above ones.

So, i believe the moshman's book is still the best out there.
There's also another book (don't know when it came, though), called `Let's play poker` by Lee Nelson, specific for SNGs (in collaboration with pokerstars). Pretty good read as well.